Why is my destination prefix given [Object Object] as its output in AWS-SDK?
I am writing this code where im using aws sdk to copy files from one place to another dir, here destinationprefix is supposed to handle to destination directory, there the variable has to be put, idk why it is always copying the file in the dir -> main-dir/[object object] even that is not what I want
here is the code
main function
async function copyS3Folder(sourcePrefix, destinationPrefix, continuationToken) {
    try {
        const listParams = {
            Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || "",
            Prefix: sourcePrefix,
            ContinuationToken: continuationToken
        };
        // console.log(` ${sourcePrefix}, ${destinationPrefix}`)
        const listedObjects = await s3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise();

        if (!listedObjects.Contents || listedObjects.Contents.length === 0) return;

        await Promise.all(listedObjects.Contents.map(async (object) => {
            if (!object.Key) return;

            let decodedKey = decodeURIComponent(object.Key); // Ensure to decode the object key
            let destinationKey = decodedKey.replace(sourcePrefix, destinationPrefix);

            let copyParams = {
                Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || "",
                CopySource: `${process.env.S3_BUCKET}/${encodeURIComponent(decodedKey)}`, // Properly encode the object key
                Key: destinationKey
            };

            await s3.copyObject(copyParams).promise();
            console.log(`Copied ${decodedKey} to ${destinationKey}`);
        }));

        if (listedObjects.IsTruncated) {
            listParams.ContinuationToken = listedObjects.NextContinuationToken;
            await copyS3Folder(sourcePrefix, destinationPrefix, listParams.ContinuationToken);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error copying folder:', error);
    }
}

and here is the calling function... where I initiate the function
    socket.on("createStartUp", async (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        await copyS3Folder(`group-source`, `main-dir/${data}`)
        console.log("success!")


I tried using ChatGpt and I debugged it to be faulting on the destination prefix where I found that the end directory is hardcoded to [object object ] but I dont know how to fix it!

Because data is an object and not a string. See here.

@jarmod can you please specify more as i am a beginner.. what can i change to make it work? Any suggestions?

What does console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) show?

in socket.on, the console log without the JSON.stringify shows the proper data... it shows as [object object ] on in the copyS3Folder function @Barmar

When it shows the 'proper data', what does it actually show? The point is that data is an object so is a composite variable. It will likely contain the actual value you need in, for example, data.bucket or data.name. But we don't know what properties data has unless you tell us.

Use JSON.stringify like I showed, so you can copy and paste the output into the question.

@Barmar I did this
async function copyS3Folder(sourcePrefix, destinationPrefix, continuationToken){
    console.log(sourcePrefix, destinationPrefix, continuationToken);
    destinationPrefix = JSON.stringify(destinationPrefix);
    console.log(sourcePrefix, destinationPrefix, continuationToken);
}


and I saw that JSON.stringify isnt making any changes in the actual value.. is there another way to do it?

@jarmod, I have an text type input box and the "data" is actually just the input data that I get.. However I am not understanding how should i write it ( and where ) to convert it into a string, as the "data " in the console log which is in the socket.on is a string because the console log is showing it with the proper data and not [object object] it is only happening in the function...

I don't know what you mean by "isn't making any changes". It's not supposed to. It just logs it in a text format so you can copy-paste it into the question. Then we can tell you what property you should use.

E.g. if you see {"filename": "blah"} you would use ${data.filename}.

@Barmar realised that and fixed it... thank you so much!!
